# How to handle dynamic form inputs with spring

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc

I have a dynamic form, which is used to save application settings for each company. As each company, has different settings, I have to generate the form dynamically.

```
<form:form id="update-user-form"
  action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/add-app-settings"
  commandName="addApsTypeSetting" class="form-horizontal">
  <c:forEach var="key" items="${appTypeSettingsKey}">
      <%--                <a href="#panelDecription" style="cursor: pointer;">${key.setting_key}</a> --%>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>

          <div class="col-md-9">
              <form:errors path="setting_key" cssClass="error" />
              <form:label path="setting_key" id="setting_key_error"
                  cssClass="error"></form:label>
          </div>
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label">${key.setting_key}</label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
              <form:input path="setting_key" cssClass="form-control" id=""
                  maxlength="50" />
          </div>
      </div>
  </c:forEach>
  <c:if test="${not empty appTypeSettingsKey}">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
              <div>
                  <!-- <a class="btn btn-primary m-r-5" style="float: right"
                      href="#modal-dialog" >Save</a> -->
                  <form:button>submit</form:button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </c:if>
</form:form>
```

I have to deal with two database table, one is for generating the settings and otherone is for saving the settings values.

Basically, I am trying to bing two objects to the form,One is to render the content and other object for saving the settings values. Can anybody help me to fix this issue? Do you need any information?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use the same object for rendering create and retrieve the form information?

I assume you have an object that store metadata that should be immutable in the form context, and another to store the form value. If that's true, you can load the metadata into an object, that is mutable and available for binding data from the form. Then you make it through.

Comment: due to the database schema structure, we have to create two tables. One is for recording application types for a company and one is recording settings for application types. It is not clear for me what you've mentioned. if you can give me an example or url, that would be great